# Table has annotations but not mapped in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

table is not mapped [[From table ]] with root cause table no mapped error

From  **com.springboot.pojos.Hero**  under  **src/main/java**

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="HEROES")
public class Hero
```

This is from my **hibernate.cfg.xml**  under  **src/main/resources**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
   <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property> 
    <mapping class="com.springboot.pojos.Hero"/>
    <mapping class="com.springboot.pojos.Abilities"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am using spring boot

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

UPDATES ================================

```
2018-05-18 21:44:59.817  INFO 2992 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1]     o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2018-05-18 21:45:00.399 ERROR 2992 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Hero is not mapped [FROM Hero]] with root cause

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Hero is not mapped
```

Query that is throwin the error

```
 String hql = "FROM Hero";
 Query query = currSession.createQuery(hql);
```

Comment: I’m not seeing any PL/SQL.

Comment: The database is ORACLE but the query Im using is Hibernates HQL

Comment: try `String hql = "FROM com.springboot.pojos.Hero";`

Comment: @The_Mente Can you please show your project structure and main class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using Hibernate annotations you can map entity to table using the way shown above. No need to configure any other files. Please provide more information on what is the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sprint boot you need to configure your data source and tell spirng boot by @EnableJpaRepositories witch is the package that contains the entities.

In your application.property you have to set the datasource variable
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", basePackages = {
        "com.getsoft.invapp.repositoty" })
//@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.getsoft.invapp.entity" });

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;

    }
```